# What svcutil.exe does Visual Studio 2013 use when adding or updating service references?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, svcutil.exe, service-reference

I am troubleshooting an issue with updating a service reference in Visual Studio 2013. I want to compare the results in Visual Studio with the results of running svcutil.exe from the command line.

I have 6 Windows SDKs on my machine, 3 of those contain svcutil.exe:

- v7.0A (one in the Bin folder)
- v8.0A (in the "bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools" folder)
- v8.1A (in the "\binNETFX 4.5.1 Tools" folder)

The project targets .NET Framework 4. Which svcutil.exe does Visual Studio 2013 use when generating or updating a service reference?

Answer (score 2):

In the visual studio command prompt, try this command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>where svcutil.exe
```

This will give the version that the framework is referring to.

Comment: Thanks, I get two results, one in the v8.0A SDK folder, and one in the v7.0A SDK folder.